# I have to create a query in which if any new row will be added into a table, a new column should be created in another table in mysql HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

| Bill Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |
| third | row |
| fourth | row |

Bill name values should be created a column in another table

| First | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

if new row is added in first table, a new column should be created on another.
Remember: I am working on Heidi-SQL and mySQL.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361). Why do you need an additional table with columns that match the row values the original table? What you are asking is possible, but it is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: basically i have to convert rows  dynamically  into column, i need additional table because i have a configuration table for my specific fields, when a field is inserted in that table, it will be converted into  a column in another table and that table is basically for jasper report query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.